# How do you find event codes for applications to use in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm working on fixing an outdated script that was created by someone else, and this is the first time I've come across event codes  / raw format, for example:

```
«event sysodlog»
```

I know that programs like Excel have app-specific event codes that can be used, however, I'm not sure how to find those for other apps. Is there a way to find them using AppleScript, or a database I haven't stumbled across yet?

Comment: You can open the app’s dictionary in Script Editor (File > Open Dictionary), save it to disk as an SDEF (XML) file, then view that in a plain text/XML editor to get the underlying AE codes. `sysodlog` is Standard Additions’ `display dialog` command.

Comment: @foo, that's exactly what I was looking for - thanks! If the app is greyed out in the list when you look for dictionaries, does that mean it's no longer available for some reason?

Comment: @rackinfrackin Yes--you either deleted the application or moved it.  But `sysodlog` is part of `scripting additions`, so I shouldn't think that's gone anywhere.